# How to Mock AutoMapper IConfigurationProvider in x-unit unit testing in asp.net core

Tags: c#, unit-testing, automapper, moq, xunit

I'm writing unit test for my `UserRepository` class where I'm using AutoMapper `ProjectTo<T>` Queryable Extensions for projection. Here is how the class looks like:

```
public class UserRepository:IUserRepository
    {
        private readonly UserManager<UserEntity> _userManager;
        private readonly IConfigurationProvider _mappingConfiguration;

        public UserRepository(
            UserManager<UserEntity> userManager,
            IConfigurationProvider mappingConfiguration)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _mappingConfiguration = mappingConfiguration;
        }

        public async Task<IEnumerable<User>> GetUsersAsync()
        {
            IQueryable<UserEntity> query = _userManager.Users;

            var size = await query.CountAsync();

            var items = await query
                .ProjectTo<User>(_mappingConfiguration)
                .ToArrayAsync();

            return items;
        }
    }
```

I'm using x-unit unit test project. Here is my test class,

```
public class UserRepositoryTests
    {
        [Fact]
        public async void GetUsers_AtleastOne_ReturnOneOrMore()
        {
            // Arrange
            var connectionStringBuilder =
                new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = ":memory:" };
            var connection = new SqliteConnection(connectionStringBuilder.ToString());

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<GallaContext>()
                .UseSqlite(connection)
                .Options;

            var mockHttpContextAccessor = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
            var mockUserManager = new Mock<UserManager<UserEntity>>(new Mock<IUserStore<UserEntity>>().Object,
                    new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                    new Mock<IPasswordHasher<UserEntity>>().Object,
                    new IUserValidator<UserEntity>[0],
                    new IPasswordValidator<UserEntity>[0],
                    new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                    new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                    new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                    new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<UserEntity>>>().Object);
            var mockAutoMapper = new Mock<IConfigurationProvider>();

            using (var context = new GallaContext(options, mockHttpContextAccessor.Object))
            {
                context.Database.OpenConnection();
                context.Database.EnsureCreated();

                var userRepository = new UserRepository( mockUserManager.Object, mockAutoMapper.Object);

                // Act
                var users = await userRepository.GetUsersAsync();

                // Assert
                users.Should().HaveCountGreaterOrEqualTo(1);
            }
        }
    }
```

I'm getting the following error when executing `ProjectTo<User>` in my repository class.

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an
>   instance of an object.    at
>   AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression.ToCore[TResult](Object
>   parameters, IEnumerable`1 memberPathsToExpand)

I'm new to Moq and Unit Testing, I searched a lot but couldn't find a way to Mock this. Please assist on how to properly Mock AutoMapper `IConfigurationProvider` along with my `MappingProfile`

Here is the Error Details

```
System.NullReferenceException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

  Source=AutoMapper

  StackTrace:
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.ProjectionExpression.ToCore[TResult](Object parameters, IEnumerable '1 memberPathsToExpand)
   at AutoMapper.QueryableExtensions.Extensions.ProjectTo[TDestination](IQueryable source, IConfigurationProvider configuration, Expression`1[] membersToExpand)
   at Repositories.UserRepository.<GetUsersAsync>d__5.MoveNext() in ..path\:line 46
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter '1.GetResult()
   at Repositories.Test.UserRepositoryTests.<GetUsers_AtleastOne_ReturnOneOrMore>d__0.MoveNext() in ..path\Repositories.Test\UserRepositoryTests.cs:line 53
```

Thanks,

Abdul

Comment: This looks more like an integration test. As for the mapper. wy not use an actual instance of one. initialize an actual mapper and use that

Comment: I have my default data added inside `OnModelCreating` in my context. That's why I'm not adding any users in my unit test. May be that made test to look like integration test. And what instance need to be created for automapper in this case?

Comment: The issue is that you don't have a `Setup` for the `IConfigurationProvider` mock, or any other mock. I would instead recommend injecting `IMapper` interface and mock the `Map` method. I will try to get back to you later tonight with a detailed answer.

Comment: Don't mock automapper, create actual instance and pass it to the repository.

Comment: @Fabio why automapper doesn't need to be mocked?

Comment: Automapper is implementation details. For example I don't want to rewrite my tests if I decide to map objects manually.

Comment: You should mock only dependencies which makes your tests slow (database, file system, web services ...) or makes you tests very very very complicated to setup.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is how I resolved following @Fabio comments and that works.

```
var mockAutoMapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc => mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile())).CreateMapper().ConfigurationProvider;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private IMapper _mapper;

protected UserRepositoryTests()
{
    var mockAutoMapper = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
    {
      //mc.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
      mc.AddMaps(typeof(DefaultApplicationDTOModule).Assembly);
    }).CreateMapper().ConfigurationProvider;

    _mapper = new Mapper(mockAutoMapper);
}
```

To improve on your answer, scanning all your MappingProfiles